# Dealing with spaces in bash when piping the results from one command to another

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, find, whitespace

I need to go recursively through several directories/files, in `bash`, replacing a certain string with another if it exists in a file. I had this solved in my script with the line:

```
grep -rl "stringToReplace" * | xargs sed -ie 's/stringToReplace/newString/'
```

until I saw that there files with names that had spaces in them. So, if there is a file called `"dir1/dir2/I Am A File.txt"`, `xargs` tries to feed 4 files to sed: `"dir1/dir2/I"`, `"Am"`, `"A"` and `"File.txt"`.

I've tried everything I can think of to get around this, but can't. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does your system's version of grep support a `-Z, --null` option?

Answer (score 1):

`grep | xargs` is not the best tool for this sort of thing, because it can't safely deal with complex filenames. However, you have a couple of options if your filenames don't contain line feeds:

```
grep -rl "stringToReplace" * | xargs -I {} sed -ie 's/stringToReplace/newString/' {}
```

This works with [any (XSI) POSIX-compatible `xargs`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html). `-I {}` forces single-line processing, and for `{}` to be replaced with the filename whenever it appears in the arguments.

With GNU grep you can use:

```
grep -rl "stringToReplace" * | xargs -d '\n' sed -ie 's/stringToReplace/newString/'
```

This explicitly uses a line feed as the delimiter instead of blanks, but is a non-portable extension.

More safely respecting any possible filename, including obtuse ones containing line feeds, is [this POSIX `find` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html):

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q "stringToReplace" {} \; -exec sed -ie 's/stringToReplace/newString/' {} +
```

It does spawn a lot of `grep`s - the first `-exec` runs once for each regular file found within the current directory, and the second only for groups of files where the first returned success (i.e. where `grep` found the pattern in the file). The extra processes probably aren't a major issue for what you're doing, but it's possible for them to dominate if there are many small files on certain filesystems.

Still-more-safely, but not as portably, the `-execdir` primary from GNU and BSD `find` will do essentially the same thing, but protected against certain renaming attacks.

Comment: With GNU grep, it can output nuls after filenames

Comment: Thank you very much! The -I {} didn't work for me at all...not sure why...but the -d option performed beautifully! What threw me for a loop is I remembered working a problem similar to this ages ago and read the results into an array of some sort, then used IFS to separate out the fields I wanted...and, for the life of me, I couldn't remember how to do it!

Comment: Note that `sed -ie` would create a backup file with the filename suffix `e`. I'm not sure this was intended, or whether it was an attempt to use the `-e` option with `sed` (not needed here).